# Application stops when starting other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have two fragments, when a layout is clicked on in fragment1, i want to start fragment 2.

Fragment 1:

```
public class NewFlightTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_flight,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final RelativeLayout departureCityLayout = ( RelativeLayout )   getActivity().findViewById( R.id.depature_city_layout);
    departureCityLayout.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add( R.id.citiesAndAirport, new CitiesAndAirportFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class CitiesAndAirportFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<String> citiesAndAirports;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_airport_list,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        citiesAndAirports.add("Bangalore");
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.citiesAndAirport);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager );
        mAdapter = new CitiesAndAirportAdapter(citiesAndAirports);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter( mAdapter );


    }
}
```

Xml file for cities_airport_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/citiesAndAirport"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
```

During the onClickListener, app crashes with no view found for id citiesAndAirport in the add() of beginTransaction().

Logs:

```
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959): Process: com.flightapp.myapp, PID: 2959
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09005a (com.flightapp.myapp:id/citiesAndAirport) for fragment CitiesAndAirportFragment{14ff52f7 #2 id=0x7f09005a}
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
03-15 02:15:07.891: E/AndroidRuntime(2959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
```

Comment: golden rule: if your app crashed always post logcat

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.citiesAndAirport);
```

to onCreteView:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_airport_list,container,false);
    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.citiesAndAirport);
    return v;
}
```

In addition in the code you put here you never initialized citiesAndAirports;

Comment: Actually it crashed while calling the add() of beginTransaction().

Comment: Try to replace R.id.citiesAndAirport  with android.R.id.content in your transaction.

Comment: The id you supply should be the id of the container you open the second fragment into/. If you want to put it in the activity layout, give the id of that root layout.